# Well I am having issue with publish button in my django site .It is not performing its' function

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using django 3.0.3,python 3.8.5 and Vs code as an IDE. I am clicking on the publish button but it is not working.

---Models.py---

```
 def publish(self):
        self.published_data = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

---views.py---

```
@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=pk)
```

---urls.py---

```
 path('post/<int:pk>/publish/',views.post_publish,name ='post_publish'),
```

--post_detail.html(template)--

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
```

--post_detail.html(Complete template)--

```
  {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="posttitle loader">{{post.title}}</h1>
{% if post.published_date %}
        <div class="date postdate">
        {{ post.published_date}}
    </div>
{% else %}
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
{% endif %}
<p class="postcontent">{{ post.text|safe|linebreaksbr}}</p>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a class= "btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.293 1.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l2 2a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.414l-9 9a1 1 0 0 1-.39.242l-3 1a1 1 0 0 1-1.266-1.265l1-3a1 1 0 0 1 .242-.391l9-9zM12 2l2 2-9 9-3 1 1-3 9-9z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.146 6.354l-2.5-2.5.708-.708 2.5 2.5-.707.708zM3 10v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H4v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H5v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H6v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H3z"/>
</svg>
</a>
<a class= "btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
</svg>
</a>
{% endif %}
<hr>
<a class="btn btn-priamy btn-comment" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
<div class="container">
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <br>
    {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.apporved_comment %}
    {{ comment.created_date }}
    {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
    <a class= "btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-x" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.854 4.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l7-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.146 4.146a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l7 7a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708l-7-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0z"/>
</svg>
</a>
<a class= "btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-check2" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.854 3.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L6.5 10.293l6.646-6.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
</svg>
</a>
{% endif %}
<P> {{ comment.text|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
<P> Posted By:{{comment.author}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
    <p>No Comments</p>
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

I am new and learning django framework and It feels so bad when I stuck on such things where I could not understand what to do but I hope you guys can able to help me.
Any help will be appreciated
**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would work that way, what i think something like this work would work:

urls.py

```
path('post/publish',views.post_publish,name ='post_publish'),
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = POST
        fields = ['title', 'text', ...] # Your post model fields
```

views.py

```
from .forms import PostForm
@login_required
def post_publish(request):
    if request.Method=='POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post_detail/'+str(pk))
    post_form = PostForm()
    return render(response, "publish.html", {"form": post_form})
```

template publish.html (of course can add other html to present however you like)

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

PostForm will automatically convert you Post model into a form, when you 'GET' publish.html, this form will be and when you click on publish button it will submit form data on same url by doing a POST. inside our view when it's POST when parse that request into a filled form then we call is_valid to clean data and make sure that all validation are satisfied. If they are then we call save function that will create the post and redirect to post detail page.

When implementing you still might run into some import errors or other, but this is to give you an idea on how to do this. let me know as you implement this and if you run into some errors.

Comment: when I am clicking on the publish button ,than it show just a blank page with same url

Comment: and is the post created?

Comment: No post wasn't created or publish

Comment: sorry, i just reviewed code and updated `def post_publish(request, pk):` to `def post_publish(request):`. Can you can make that change in your code, runserver again and let me know about the results?

Comment: Yeah sure but i dont understand this following part of your code

Comment: post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

Comment: dont you think that should be ,if post_form.is__valid ,post_form.save()

Comment: no, no. it's **form.is_valid()**. [from_the_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror)

Comment: Oky but its still not publishing and I guess There is csrf token token is missig in form.py

Comment: even After csrf_token its still showing blank page..

Comment: my bad again, **csrf_token** added in form, answer updated.

Comment: idk man, if you are doing it for learning purposes and can publish code on github public, share link with me and i will take a look. otherwise there is no way to tell.

Comment: I mentioned github link ,you can check if am wrong somewhere

Comment: change line 25 in views.py to **login_url =reverse_lazy('login')**, and make you have applied all migrations before running server. after this i was able to create post just find by going to /post/new and it was created too. all worked fine.

Comment: after creating post go into draft and than i when i go into draft and try to publish. It does not publish that.. and I am having still same issue after editing views.py and performing all migrations